# Single Source Code vs Multiple Files + Libraries

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, libraries

How much effect does having multiple files or compiled libraries vs. throwing everything (>10,000 LOC) into one source have on the final binary? For example, instead of linking a Boost library separately, I paste its code, along with my original source, into one giant file for compilation. And along the same line, instead of feeding several files into `gcc`, pasting them all together, and giving only that one file.

I'm interested in the optimization differences, instead of problems (horror) that would come with maintaining a single source file of gargantuan proportions.

Granted, there can only be link-time optimization (I may be wrong), but is there a lot of difference between optimization possibilities?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - are you asking the difference between the output program depending on whether you have one giant source file or several?

Comment: @Carl I think he means linking precompiled units vs. feeding everything to the compiler at the same time. Could you clarify, Alex?

Comment: I've rephrased the question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the compiler can see all source code, it can optimize better if your compiler has some kind of [**Interprocedural Optimization (IPO)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization) option turned on. IPO differs from other compiler optimization because it **analyzes the entire program**; other optimizations look at only a single function, or even a single block of code

Here is some interprocedural optimization that can be done, [see here for more](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2009/compiler_c/optaps/common/optaps_ipo_mult.htm):

- Inlining
- Constant propagation
- mod/ref analysis
- Alias analysis
- Forward substitution
- Routine key-attribute propagation
- Partial dead call elimination
- Symbol table data promotion
- Dead function elimination
- Whole program analysis

[GCC supports this kind of optimization.](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-profiling.html)

This interprocedural optimization can be used to analyze and optimize the function being called.

If compiler can not see the source code of the library function, it cannot do such optimization.

Comment: Does this mean that by compiling two source files separately, the function calls between the two files won't gain such optimizations? For example, calling `gcc -c a.c` then `gcc -c b.c` before `gcc a.o b.o`

Comment: Some compiler provides flag to performs optimizations across all object files in the link step, so not limited to just the source files of the compile command. Object files compiled with this flag have analysis information embedded within them that enables interprocedural analysis across source and pre-compiled files. This is done in the final link step, so the compilation of the source files need not all take place in a single compilation and could take place over a number of separate compilations. But of course, this separate compilations may prevent certain interprocedural optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

Note that some modern compilers (clang/LLVM, icc and recently even gcc) now support link-time-optimization (LTO) to minimize the effect of separate compilation. Thus you gain the benefits of separate compilation (maintenance, faster compilation, etc.) and these of whole program analysis.

By the way, it seems like gcc has supported -fwhole-program and --combine since version 4.1. You have to pass all source files together, though.

Finally, since BOOST is *mostly* header files (templates) that are #included, you cannot gain anything from adding these to your source code.